# Running invisible recaptcha when loading the page

Tags: recaptcha

Is it allowed to use invisible recaptcha linked to the onload as shown in the image below?

```html
  <div id='recaptcha' class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="site_key" data-callback="do_something" data-size="invisible"></div>
  <script defer>
    window.onload = function() {
      grecaptcha.execute();
    }
    function do_something(token) {
      ...
    }
  </script>
```

I'm scared of being banned according to google rules. Also, if it's not prohibited, I wanted to know if it's a good practice to run the captcha linked to the onload.